# Getting groups as a list from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, grouping

I am following emaze-dysfunctional to grouping from a arraylist. In follwing code I can group from the map. Console shows grouping elements. I need to add them in a arraylist.

For ex. repay liat is having 120 elements, but grouping map contains three groups as 40 elements each.

```
        List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> repay = loanService
                .getLoanRepaymentScheduleById(groupLoan.getLoanId());

        Map<Integer, List<LoanRepaymentSchedule>> map = Groups.groupBy(
                repay, new Pluck<Integer, LoanRepaymentSchedule>(
                        LoanRepaymentSchedule.class, "memberCount"));
        System.out.println ("map.keySet().size() "+map.keySet().iterator());

        for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
            List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> pro =  map.get(key);
            System.out.println("Element-******* "+pro.size());          
            System.out.println("Element-******* "+pro.get(0));          

        }
```

How to save that 3 grouping elements in a separate arraylist like list1, list2, list3.

repay list as follows,

```
    id 1 val 5
    id 1 val 6
    id 1 val 1
    id 1 val 5
    id 1 val 6
    id 1 val 1
```

I need list 1 as

```
id 1 val 5
id 1 val 5
```

list 2 as

```
id 1 val 6
id 1 val 6
```

list 1 as

```
id 3 val 1
id 1 val 1
```

Comment: What do you need the lists (1, 2, 3) for?

Comment: to understand id is the key? and 5 or 6 are the pro.get(0);?

Comment: What exactly do you need? You already have different lists stored in your Map. Don't these lists already contain what you want?

Comment: @Eran i think he has one list and he want to sort it in 3 different lists

Comment: @Mohammed Housseyn Taleb, you are exactly...

Comment: @Mary.Hansen take a look at my code it really may help is the idea if it works i don't know i need all the code to test. but try it.

Comment: Thanks Maohammaed. Sure I will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add the 3 lists to a single list.

You can simply do :

```
    List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> output = new ArrayList<LoanRepaymentSchedule>();
    for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
        output.addAll(map.get(key));        
    }
```

BTW, I'm not familiar with this `Groups` class, but Java 8 has a more simple syntax for the same functionality :

```
Map<Integer, List<LoanRepaymentSchedule>> = 
    repay.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(LoanRepaymentSchedule::getMemberCount);
```

Assuming `LoanRepaymentSchedule` has a `getMemberCount` method by which you are grouping the `LoanRepaymentSchedule` instances.

Comment: i m bad in english, he is not asking to save all the data on 3 different Lists ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    try this ? 

     ArrayList[] lists=new ArrayList[3];
    for (ArrayList list : lists) {
        list=new ArrayList();
    }
    boolean firstInsert=true;
    int i=0;
     for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
        List<LoanRepaymentSchedule> pro =  map.get(key);
        System.out.println("Element-******* "+pro.size());          
        System.out.println("Element-******* "+pro.get(0));
         try {

             if (firstInsert) {
                 if (lists[0].isEmpty()) {
                     lists[0].add(pro);
                     break;
                 }
                 if (lists[1].isEmpty()) {
                     lists[1].add(pro);
                     break;
                 }
                 if (lists[2].isEmpty()) {
                     lists[2].add(pro);
                     firstInsert=false;
                     break;
                 }
             }

             if(pro.get(0)==lists[0].get(lists[0].size()-1)){lists[0].add(pro);
        }
             if(pro.get(0)==lists[1].get(lists[1].size()-1)){lists[1].add(pro);
        }
             if(pro.get(0)==lists[2].get(lists[2].size()-1)){lists[2].add(pro);
        }
         } catch (Exception e) {
         }


    }
```

Comment: then the first list is in the array loop as you wish. if it works i don't have how to try it.